# SQL: select with disctint left

Tags: sql, postgresql

table

```
            id name   data
            ---------------
            1  name1  data1
            2  name2  data2
            3  name3  data3
            4  name4  data1abc
            5  name5  data2abc
            6  name6  data1abcd
            7  name7  data2abcde
```

The output that I need is rows with ids 3, 6 and 7.

I need to search for distinct data terms. The terms data1, data1abc, data1abcd should all be counted as one term and the rows with unique most characters should be returned i.e., data1abcd, data2abcde, data3

Can you help please?

This is what I have written so far, it doesnt work:

```
            SELECT *
            FROM table
            WHERE LEFT(data, 5) = (
                SELECT distinct LEFT(data, 5)
                FROM table
                )
```

Comment: I see why you want id 3, but how come you chose 6 and 7?

Comment: we are looking for unique data results in the table(for example here data1, data2, data3) but data1, data1abc, data1abcd are all the same type of data, so we need to get data1abcd instead of data1 because it has most number of characters beginning with data1. Similarly for data2, there are three rows, data2, data2abc, data2abcde so the one with most number of characters beginning with data2 which is 'data2abcde' should be returned. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 2):

This will work for any string length:

```
select s
from (
    select
        s,
        case
            when s = left(lag(s) over (order by s desc), length(s))
            then false else true
        end as u
    from t
) t
where u
order by s
;
     s      
------------
 data1abcd
 data2abcde
 data3
```

Sample data:

```
create table t (id int, name text, s text);

insert into t (id, name, s) values
(1, 'name1', 'data1'),
(2, 'name2', 'data2'),
(3, 'name3', 'data3'),
(4, 'name4', 'data1abc'),
(5, 'name5', 'data2abc'),
(6, 'name6', 'data1abcd'),
(7, 'name7', 'data2abcde');
```

Comment: wow this is excellent, thanks.. if there is one change in the data, like (1, 'name1', 'data1*'),
(2, 'name2', 'data2*'),
(3, 'name3', 'data3*'),
(4, 'name4', 'data1abc*'),
(5, 'name5', 'data2abc*'),
(6, 'name6', 'data1abcd*'),
(7, 'name7', 'data2abcde*');

can you suggest a solution please?

Comment: @lambda8 You mean the asterisk is a global match? It changes everything. Please open another question for that.

Answer (score 0):

You could partition the rows by the first five characters and take the longest:

```
SELECT name, data
FROM   (SELECT name, 
               data,
               RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY LEFT(data, 5) 
                            ORDER BY LENGTH(data) DESC) AS rk
        FROM   mytable) t
WHERE  rk = 1
```

Note:
The `rank` function allows for ties (e.g., `data1a` and `data1b` have the same length, so they could both have the rank of 1 if there a no longer strings). If you do not want to allow for ties, you should use `row_number` instead.

Answer (score -1):

It seems that you want distinct non-numeric values. You may change data_len as len(data_r) if you want the longest non-numeric records

```
ALTER TABLE <yourtable>
ADD 
 data_r as REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE (data, '0', ''),'1', ''),'2', ''),'3', ''),'4', ''),'5', ''),'6', ''),'7', ''),'8', ''),'9', '')
,data_len as len(data)

SELECT * FROM <yourtable> t
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT MAX(data_len), data_r 
               FROM <yourtable> t1
               WHERE t.data_r = t1.data_r
               AND t.data_len = t1.data_len
               GROUP BY data_r
             )
```